# How to fix Code Climate test reporter failing in CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, circleci, code-climate

I am trying to add the Code Climate Test Reporter to a Rails app where I am using CircleCI.

I have followed the setup instructions along with the error messages I am getting when CircleCI runs the build, however, I am a bit stuck now. My tests all pass (locally and in CircleCI) but I am still getting an error.

Have anyone seen an error like this? If so, any suggestions for getting the Code Climate Test Reporter to work correctly with CircleCI? As the error output suggests, I have stubbed out the response in my spec_helper.rb.

Thanks for your help. Please let me know if I need to include more information.

Here are the steps Code Climate said to complete along with the error output:

1. add the code climate gem

   gem list codeclimate-test-reporter

   codeclimate-test-reporter (0.5.0)
2. add test reporter in spec_helper.rb (you can also see the stub_request from the error message in the config.before(:each) block at the bottom. This is my spec_helper.rb.

   require "codeclimate-test-reporter"

   CodeClimate::TestReporter.start

   ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'

   require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', **FILE**)

   require 'rspec/rails'
   require 'shoulda/matchers'
   require 'webmock/rspec'

   Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }

   RSpec.configure do |config|
     config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
       c.syntax = :expect
     end

   config.include Features, type: :feature 
     config.include Formulaic::Dsl, type: :feature

   config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
     config.order = 'random'
     config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
     config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

   config.before(:each) do
       stub_request(:post, "https://codeclimate.com/test_reports").
         with(:body => "\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\xE0\xC1\u0012W........
           :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Encoding'=>'gzip', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Code Climate (Ruby Test Reporter v0.5.0)'}).
          to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})·
       end
     end

   ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema! 
   Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
   WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
3. Code Climate test reporter token (i copied this into the CircleCI environment variables screen from the code climate test reporter setup screen)

   CODECLIMATE_REPO_TOKEN  xxxxb0c8

Here is my error output from CircleCI:

```
bundle exec rspec --color spec --format progress
I, [2016-04-18T05:16:18.343024 #12231] INFO -- : Reporting coverage data to Code Climate.
/home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use rails generate simple_form:install to generate the Simple Form configuration.
.............

Finished in 1.24 seconds
13 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 45226

Coverage = 100.0%. Sending report to https://codeclimate.com for branch contact_form... /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/webmock-1.24.0/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:114:in request': Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST https://codeclimate.com/test_reports with body '���mW��X�n�8�=g�/����á#DC�����5m�X�s���"%��3g�P���y�������h\����8��1j�N��d}A (WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError)
*{UP�:Z��P]TӰ��Ҵ4U�_�:�W�v{�C?�C��8]�}� ������c�w�vHu�yU�EA2Ep)��"xk�JK# L
�E8����[_�E�kۧ���?gP���;���Z
q)�ǧy�~3���e�mz�����<T�0C[]�_�kuQu�4-�����(�-�-�l:T�D&�(�ǐ���+�iހ��)��
�>�?��Z��@-�H�D$��R,
����&.��ȂYO�"z�U�D,�����p���ĕ�7��u��Pa�-�8|���Yx���
:��c���p,��\|0����20�B  9����WG��/���K���� �T��z#t�Fert��d��z�6��� �}F2�/I�8���
Ğ�M�s*�����b�]�S1���y���}��h�
{qt�#�3�O<��6���F�@��$��<�
w�dn��G�-.@2K��D������W�|���adڮ�3h�X�m���J��K�X��m���C�~��>E��(_/�q�װ��8��A�+�q�ڸ�ዊ��P��.�NtQm�yY{C��D2x�BK��D,1��J"'�W�K�g����k�w���X��4B�7O�4�uƮ�o�5>��˭O]��-��-!�z{����f��j���?�g���дS=r�{j��t[.r�ݫ37���E4x����b�-6�C�k����d^3b��B�]�ff�iJC#?�KU�=���xO���� �@��' with headers {'Accept'=>'/', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Encoding'=>'gzip', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Code Climate (Ruby Test Reporter v0.5.0)'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:post, "https://codeclimate.com/test_reports").
with(:body => "\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\xA5m\u0014W\u0000\u0003\xCDX\xDBn\xDB8\u0010\xFD\u0017=g\u0013\xDE/\xF9\x95\xA2\u0010\x86á#D\u0017C\x92\x93\xEE\u0006\xF9\xF7\u001D5m\xE3X\xB5s\x81\x83\u0016\u0001\f\x89\"%\x9E\xE1\x993g\xF2P\x8D\xB4\u001D\xEAy\xB8\xA5\xBE\xBA\xAE\x82\xA1h\\x88\x94\u001D\x99\u0012\xD08\e\x8B\xD71j\x90N\x89\u0000d}A \n*{\u0011UP\u000E\x92\u0017:Z\xE7\x93\xC0P]TӰ\e\x91\xEAҴ4U\xD7_\u001E\xAA\u001E:\xE2W\xC3v{\x85C?\x8FC\xDB\xD28]\xF1}\xDB \xCC\xCD\xD0\xD7\xCF\xE3\x97c\xE2w\xA4vHu\x93yU\u000E\xDAEA2Ep)\xE7\u0000\"xk\x92\u000EJK\u001F# \u0015L\n\x96E8\xDC\xD1\b\x9B\xE5[\xE4E\xBFkۧ\x9F\xA7\xEB\xAF?gP\xAE\xB7\xC4;\xEC\xE7\xEAZ\nq)\x9Eǧy\xA4~3\xDF\xF0\x83e\xB8mz\xE2\xAD\xED\xFA\x99\x81\xF3\xABkuQu\xCD4-\x97\xE2\xF1\xF1\xE2(\xD6-\xE0-\xEFl:\u0001T\xC5D&\xA1(\xC1ǐ\xB4\xCC\xCE+\xE9\u0012i\fހ\u0000\xE9)\u0005\xAD\xCB\n\xE8>\xD4?\u000E\xF4\x9EZ\u001C\xBA\x93@-\xB3H\xE5D$\xB4\xC4R,\nT!&\xA9\x9D\xC6b\xB2\xCBI\xA5\xE0\xD2\xFAD\xFF8\xD0\ej\xB7\x87\xCC}\u001A[\xB1\x96\xF8\xE4|4\u0016\u001D\xD8\xC8\aJI0U\xA5\xF7\xB9萄\xA5\u0018P\u0015\xF1[֞\r\x97\xDA\xC3%\x8F\xE0\xE2s*\xCDf\u001F\xD2!\u0016']\u0006#|\xC9%\xBAཊ\x85\xF7P4)\x95Ddq\xC8Y#\x9C\xCC\xC0翗g\xB8\x9F\xA1\xFB\u0013\xE4z\xE1\xB1\xC5\u001F\xFB9[\x90\x8D\xD9g\x8F8\u001D\xE64\f\xF3*\u001F\xC8\u0016\x81\xB2\u0000\x8A\x84\x99l\x88\xDAY-\x80\x83^2\xE7JB(\u0016\x9C9\x88\xEF\x8B0\x9D\u000F\xCD\eR\xE1\a\u0016\xEA\xEF\x9Aq\xE8;\xFE\xD6!$.\u000F9\x8A\x8C\xCE\xCAh\xB8D\xC4\"9\xA5c\xB4\xBA\u0014a\xBC7\xE4\xB5\xD7\u009F\x80tf\\oI\xF15\xAE\xE9j\xA6i\x85.g\f\u0010\xB5\xB2V\u0014\xCFUR\u0018k#\xA7D\x88^\u0014祱\xB2PR\x87\a\xF6\u001A{O\xA6Ưl8~\xF7\xBE7\u001D\x9Fq>.\xC9}\xFDy%\xEAM\xDF\xCC\r\xB4\xCD\u007F\x8B\xC0&.\x97\xF3ȂYO\xEC\"z\xE4\xB1U\xD6D\u001D,\xB2\x9A\xFA\x98\xB2p\u0010\xB2\xD2\xCAĕ\xB57\xF3\u0013\x9Bu\xB1\xE9Pa\xCF-\f\xE28|\xBF\x87\xFE\u0015Yx\u0001\u001E\x87\xE1\xB6\xE1\n:\xD1\xF8c\xEC\u0010\xBB\x87\u0005p,\xA2\xC4\\|0\x89\x8D\x99\xCF20\xE7B\t9\xA0\xF7\x82\x92WG\xB1\x9F/\xAF\xF4\xDBK\xCC\v\x90\xB9\x99 \xB5T\u007F\xEB\xDAz\v#t\xAB\u0003Fert\xEC\xFA\u001Cd\xAB\u0014\b\xE5\u0005z\x926\x82\x8F\xD2\t\x91}F2\xF6/\u0006I\xE38\xAC\x99\xEB\x93\nĞ\x80M\xB3s*\xB3\xB6\x87\u0000\xD2\u0006b\xE9\xB0]\xC2S1\xF4\xAA\xFFy\xAF\x94\xBC}\xD2\xE7h\xB0\n{qt\xEF\x88#\xB7\u00123\x8DO<\xA1\xE5\xAA\u001D6\x9B\xA6\xDF\u001CF\xD6@\x8C\x86$\xF9\x94<\x92\n\xCC\u000Fd/\r\xD9\u0004n\u001FB\x94L\u0019B+Ok\xC2\xE7\u0014\xD3\xF7\xF0\xA6\xE9KK\xB8x\xB1\u0015y\xD8$h\x9D8\xEF1\u0018'\x85\xD4Jd\x8F\x89\u0014X.S\xE0\eB\u0011ûe\xEF\u0013\xCD\xD3\t\x8D\x94\xEE\x83\"\xD95\u001D\xD5\xF3\xBF[ZE(\xA3\f\x91\x8D*[S\x89\u001A\u001C\x8B\x88\xD7\u0005\x8A7\x8E\x94\xB6%9S\xD0\xE4\xE3\xE2x~\x94\xE6\x83 \xB9\u0002\xDE\xD63#\u001Dv+\u0013\u0002Ƹ\xC51j\x8A9\b\u0015ـ\x8B\xA0،(\u001F\b\xB5WY\x92TJ\u001F\xAA\xC8\xD9\xC8-?Hii\x9C\xA6y\u0018\xE9\u0010U\xC8Fr)/ML1\xB1\xC2s\xF7+\x8CJ\x890\xE5\u0014Q\xA2/E\u001E\xF6\u001A\u007F\x93\xE8ߏ\xB0}\x96\xAA\u0015=5\u001F\rw\u007F\xB6dn\x9E\xA2G\xEC-\u0015.\u0004\u000E@2K\x83\xA4D\xD1\xFC\xD6\u001A\x9F\xD0\xEBW\u0014\xFF|\xA7\xFE\x8E\u0006adڮ\xF33h\xE7X\x8Fm\u0006\x9F\xBD\xF1J\x98\x94K\xF1\u0005X\xD5\u0002\u001A\xB6m\x8B\x9D\x81C\x91~\xEE\xFF>E\x9E\xF5\v(_/\xAAq\xD7װ\xBC\xD88\u0011\xAD\xB3A\x9E+\x82q\xBF\fڸ\xFFዊ\x89\xB3P\xA9\xBA.\xD0NtQm\x9AyY{C\xF0\xFD\u007FD2x\xCCBK\u0003\xE4\xC0D,1\xA5\xECJ\"'\u0012\xB7W\x85K\u0000g\x88\xFB\u001E\xA1\xAEk\xE6\x99w\xB5\x87\xC2X\xD6\xDB4B\x8F7O\xC74\u0003\xCEu\u0019Ʈ\xE2o\xEF5>\xDF\xF7˭O]\u0016\u001E\xDF\u000F\xE3-\xCF\u001F\xA7-!\xBFz{\xBF\xEC\xE5\xEAf\xE8\xE8j\x97\u0018\xDE\xF2?\x8Cg\xF7\x8D\u001F\x8FдS=r\xA7{j\xD6\xD4t[.r\xC3ݫ37\xD4\xD5\u001C\xADE4x\x9A\xB8\xB4\x97b\xD9-6\x8BC\xBEk\x90\x96\xCD\xFEd^3b\x8B\xCDB\xB8]\xD3ff\u001C\x83iJC#?\x94KU\xFC=\xFA\x9F\xF1\xAA\xA7\exO\x9C\u001F\u001F\xFF\a\x94\xB3\t\xA6@\u0015\u0000\u0000",
:headers => {'Accept'=>'/', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Content-Encoding'=>'gzip', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Code Climate (Ruby Test Reporter v0.5.0)'}).
to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

============================================================
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/codeclimate-test-reporter-0.5.0/lib/code_climate/test_reporter/client.rb:67:in post_results'
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/codeclimate-test-reporter-0.5.0/lib/code_climate/test_reporter/formatter.rb:29:informat'
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplecov-0.11.2/lib/simplecov/result.rb:47:in format!'
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplecov-0.11.2/lib/simplecov/configuration.rb:172:inblock in at_exit'
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplecov-0.11.2/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:67:in call'
from /home/ubuntu/msd-redux/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/simplecov-0.11.2/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:67:inblock in '

((bundle exec rspec "--color" "" "spec" --format "progress")) returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to code climate docs, you need to allow webmock to make external requests: https://docs.codeclimate.com/v1.0/docs/test-coverage-troubleshooting-tips#section--known-error-messages- . Said that, you need to add `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` or `WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)` just before `CodeClimate::TestReporter.start` call (in that case i think you must ensure your web mocks are configured correctly.)